# Empty ResultSet of PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I run the following Java code:

```
String qry = "SELECT QUOTE(?) AS cleaned";
PreparedStatement getQuote = MySQLSingleton.getInstance().conn.prepareStatement(qry);
getQuote.setString(1, clean_string);
ResultSet resultSet = getQuote.executeQuery();
System.out.println("FIRST: " + resultSet.first());
System.out.println("GET STRING: " + resultSet.getString(1));
```

The output of this is:

```
FIRST: true
GET STRING: null
```

Neither `resultSet.getString(1);` nor `resultSet.getString("cleaned");` return anything but `null`.

**Edit:** 
Running the statement directly in MySQL works without problems.

Comment: I should add: Other queries work fine with the same connection.

Comment: Have you tried calling resultSet.next() then calling resultSet.getString("cleaned") ?

Comment: .first() moves the pointer to the first row (and should return false if there is no first row). I tried .next() with the same result.

Comment: Yes calling first() or next() should both do that but sometimes wierd things happen so I thought I would ask. Have you ran the query against the db directly to see the result of the query?

Comment: `MySQLSingleton.getInstance().conn` eeeeek.

Comment: @ChadNC: I know what you mean ;) Also I ran it on MySQL directly without problems.

Comment: @BalusC: Whats wrong with that? :)

Comment: is quote() a db function or stored proc?

Comment: Threadsafety, transactional and resource leaking problems. It does not necessarily relate to your current problem, but you'll get serious problems on long term, for sure when the app is used by multiple concurrent users/threads.

Comment: @BalusC: I run a lot of statements and thought this would save the overhead of opening a lot of new connections. What are the best practices to do this? I would be very grateful for a link further explaining this.

Comment: @ChadNC: It's a MySQL function

Answer (score 1):

```
String qry = "SELECT QUOTE(?) AS cleaned";
PreparedStatement getQuote = MySQLSingleton.getInstance().conn.prepareStatement(qry);
getQuote.setString(1, clean_string);
ResultSet resultSet = getQuote.executeQuery();
resultSet.first();
System.out.println(resultSet.getFetchSize());
```

In your java code, i think it's right.

**EDIT:**

You should know that `GetFetchSize()` does not return the number of records in the `ResultSet`.`GetFetchSize()` returns the number of records that database fetch to your applicaton at a time. By default, the fetch size is 10. So fetch returns 0 because you don't work with database tables.

Comment: Yeah man, i see it now but now we are discusing about JDBC and Java.

Comment: There is no FROM clause in this because the statement doesn't relate to any table. It should just return the quoted text-

Comment: Hi Sajmon, thank you, you were right about the fetch size. The problem remains nonetheless: resultSet.first() shows true, resultSet.getString(1) and resultSet.getString("cleaned") both return null.

Comment: So it occurred to me not just, i'm glad that everything is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works super fine for me.

```
String qry = "SELECT QUOTE(?) AS cleaned";
PreparedStatement getQuote = con.prepareStatement(qry);
getQuote.setString(1, "sdafsdaf");
ResultSet resultSet = getQuote.executeQuery();
System.out.println("FIRST: " + resultSet.first());
System.out.println("GET STRING: " + resultSet.getString(1));
```

Output:

> FIRST: true
>
> GET STRING: 'sdafsdaf'

The only change in my version is variable **clean_string**. Can you make sure the value of **clean_string** is valid(not-null).

Comment: @Thomas Did you try printing the value of "clean_string"

Comment: It worked for me with your String too, but I tried it i.e. with this String, which doesn't work: `getQuote.setString(1, "(they’ve been down about 18 hours it appears)");`

Comment: It worked for me even with above string. Output : FIRST: true
GET STRING: '(they’ve been down about 18 hours it appears)'

Comment: Strange.... I hate this esoteric bugfixing. If I try the statement with the above String directly in MySQL, it works for me too. In Java I just get the `null`.